# Use jira-rest-java-client java library in Java/gradle/groovy?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, jira

I have gradle script which is creating the version in JIRA using the REST API.
But there is  jira-rest-java-client also available. I want to use the java library of  jira-rest-java-client and wants to do the same stuff in gradle. Can someone provide an example how could I try this.

How to use the jira-rest-java-client library to make connection with JIRA through example?

In Java I am trying to use this JRCJ Library but getting below error through Intellj

```
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.JiraRestClient;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.*;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.input.ComplexIssueInputFieldValue;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.input.FieldInput;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.input.TransitionInput;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.ServerVersionConstants;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;



/**
 * A sample code how to use JRJC library
 *
 * @since v0.1
 */
public class Example1 {

    private static URI jiraServerUri = URI.create("http://localhost:2990/jira");
    private static boolean quiet = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, JSONException, IOException {
        parseArgs(args);

        final AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
        final JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, "admin", "admin");
        try {
            final int buildNumber = restClient.getMetadataClient().getServerInfo().claim().getBuildNumber();

            // first let's get and print all visible projects (only jira4.3+)
            if (buildNumber >= ServerVersionConstants.BN_JIRA_4_3) {
                final Iterable<BasicProject> allProjects = restClient.getProjectClient().getAllProjects().claim();
                for (BasicProject project : allProjects) {
                    if (project == TEST){
                    println(project);}else {
                        System.out.println("Project" + "Not Found");
                    }
                }
            }

            // let's now print all issues matching a JQL string (here: all assigned issues)
            if (buildNumber >= ServerVersionConstants.BN_JIRA_4_3) {
                final SearchResult searchResult = restClient.getSearchClient().searchJql("assignee is not EMPTY").claim();
                for (BasicIssue issue : searchResult.getIssues()) {
                    println(issue.getKey());
                }
            }

            final Issue issue = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue("TST-7").claim();

            println(issue);

            // now let's vote for it
            restClient.getIssueClient().vote(issue.getVotesUri()).claim();

            // now let's watch it
            final BasicWatchers watchers = issue.getWatchers();
            if (watchers != null) {
                restClient.getIssueClient().watch(watchers.getSelf()).claim();
            }

            // now let's start progress on this issue
            final Iterable<Transition> transitions = restClient.getIssueClient().getTransitions(issue.getTransitionsUri()).claim();
            final Transition startProgressTransition = getTransitionByName(transitions, "Start Progress");
            restClient.getIssueClient().transition(issue.getTransitionsUri(), new TransitionInput(startProgressTransition.getId()))
                    .claim();

            // and now let's resolve it as Incomplete
            final Transition resolveIssueTransition = getTransitionByName(transitions, "Resolve Issue");
            final Collection<FieldInput> fieldInputs;

            // Starting from JIRA 5, fields are handled in different way -
            if (buildNumber > ServerVersionConstants.BN_JIRA_5) {
                fieldInputs = Arrays.asList(new FieldInput("resolution", ComplexIssueInputFieldValue.with("name", "Incomplete")));
            } else {
                fieldInputs = Arrays.asList(new FieldInput("resolution", "Incomplete"));
            }
            final TransitionInput transitionInput = new TransitionInput(resolveIssueTransition.getId(), fieldInputs, Comment
                    .valueOf("My comment"));
            restClient.getIssueClient().transition(issue.getTransitionsUri(), transitionInput).claim();
        }
        finally {
            restClient.close();
        }
    }

    private static void println(Object o) {
        if (!quiet) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }

    private static void parseArgs(String[] argsArray) throws URISyntaxException {
        final List<String> args = Lists.newArrayList(argsArray);
        if (args.contains("-q")) {
            quiet = true;
            args.remove(args.indexOf("-q"));
        }

        if (!args.isEmpty()) {
            jiraServerUri = new URI(args.get(0));
        }
    }

    private static Transition getTransitionByName(Iterable<Transition> transitions, String transitionName) {
        for (Transition transition : transitions) {
            if (transition.getName().equals(transitionName)) {
                return transition;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Error:

```
xception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/atlassian/sal/api/executor/ThreadLocalContextManager
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.create(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:35)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:42)
    at Example1.main(Example1.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.atlassian.sal.api.executor.ThreadLocalContextManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

Moreover I added the JRJC api,core jar in External Libraries but still getting this error?

Could someone tell me what is the issue or where am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-core:4.0.0'
compile 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-api:4.0.0'
```

Simple connection to JIRA:

```
        JiraRestClient restClient = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory().createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(new URI("https://" + jira_domain),
                jira_username, jira_password);
```